# What is the simplest way to keep an effect ongoing after hover

Tags: css, hover

I've a h1 text that is very faded on a background. Once you roll over it / hover over the block that it is in, it slowly start to light up until it is completely white. This is great and just like I want it to be. Here's the problem. Once you leave the hover, the color goes back to being faded. I'd like for it to stay white as the whole point of having it faded is that it should not be in your sight until you are hovering past it.

**TL:DR** / When I hover a h1 it starts to light up, I want the new color to remain after you remove the hover.

**The HTML I use**

```
<h1 style="color: #fff;">Sammen flytter vi<br> de digitale grænser.</h1>
```

**The CSS I use**

```
.lovernemarketingtitle h1 { 
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 54px;
    font-weight: 900;
    opacity: 0.5;
}


.lovernemarketingtitle:hover h1 {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-out;
}
```

**SOLUTION BY PRAVEEN KUMAR**

http://jsbin.com/dufarofoto/1/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 3):

Use `transition-delay`, but beware, improper use affects the hovered state as well.

```css
a {text-decoration: none; display: inline-block; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #ccc; border-radius: 3px; line-height: 1; color: #000; transition: all 0.5s linear 2s;}
a:hover {transition: all 0.5s linear 0s; background: #ccf;}
```

```html
<a href="#">Hover Me</a><br />
Lights up immediately but goes back after 2 seconds.
```

ps: There's no `opacity: 2`.

Comment: Hi ty so much for your answer! Fixed the opacity part now. I added the html I used to the original post, maybe that helps. I tried editing your code in but could not make it work (my fault of course). 

I am trying to make it work on a h1 and not a text button, sorry for not being more specific. 

Before hover = 0.5 opacity
Once you hover = I'd like it to go to 1 opacity slowly (in like 1 sec) and if anyone removes hover it just remains there it does not fade out again.

Comment: @eMikkelsen Nice, is there anything else that needs fixing? You want something like my example right?

Comment: @eMikkelsen It takes 2 seconds mate.

Comment: Hello yes, I edited the comment now, sorry for the confusion. Also as for the html/css I used everything is working except for the maintaining the color once you stop hovering :)

Comment: @eMikkelsen make a jsBin.com may be?

Comment: Done - thank you

To edit = http://jsbin.com/roqalahavi/edit?html,css,js,console,output
To view = http://jsbin.com/roqalahavi/

Comment: Hello thank you a lot. That worked I will edit your answer to the original post. Is there any way to make it finish the effect even if the hover is removed? So it continues to go towards the 1 opacity instead of stopping as the hover is removed?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to ask @eMikkelsen